# mercurial: How to archive up to the latest changeset?

Tags: mercurial

I have a weird situation here:

when I go on my hg server and do a

```
sudo hg archive /project/export
```

It archives it, but in the hidden `.hg_archival.txt` file I see

```
branch: default
latesttag: null
latesttagdistance: 31
```

But the latest checkin was 33. Which seems ignored.

Previously I had to remove changeset 32

```
hg clone <old repo> <new repo> -r 31
```

And added later two new checkins...

Could this be the reason for the hickup? What can I do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely aren't updated to the tip.  Run `hg parent`.  `hg archive` will archive the current  parent, so you are probably on local revision 31, not 33.  After you cloned to 31 and pulled the new checkins, did you `hg update`?

Comment: Thanks Mark, Yes I had done an update. In fact I can get rev 33 by pulling from my laptop. I ended up in deleting the repo directory on the server. Then create the directory and do a `hg init`. Then I simply pushed the code from laptop back to server. Everything is back incl. the history. Now I did the `hg parent`, as you suggested. And If try to archive is says `abort: no working directory: please specify a revision`. If I do `hg archive --rev 33` it gives me what I need. But its  hassle that I have to check what the latest rev is. How can I specify the top?

Comment: ahhh I had to do a `hg update` on the server as well now. Now I don't need to specify the --rev when doing an archive any longer. Very nice and its the tip now.   Thanks for your help

Comment: You can also do `hg archive tip`.  `tip` always represents the latest changeset.